# SWIG, Python packages and Visual Studio

Tags: python, c++, visual-studio, swig

I started to swig existing C++ library with the structure similar to the following:

```
namespace MainNS
{
    namespace A
    {
        class Class
        {
            //...
        };
    }

    namespace B
    {
        class Class
        {
            //...
        };
    }

    //...
}
```

Everything works as expected, except that I'm having troubles with creating Python package hierarchy. Desired hierarchy would be:

```
MainNSpack/
MainNSpack/__init__.py
MainNSpackage/Apack/
MainNSpackage/Apack/__init__.py
MainNSpackage/Apack/Class.py
MainNSpackage/Bpack/
MainNSpackage/Bpack/__init__.py
MainNSpackage/Bpack/Class.py
```

I'm trying to follow the instructions in SWIG Docs here http://www.swig.org/Doc3.0/Python.html#Python_nn72, and it's clear that I must define this dir structure and create **init** files on my own. Based on the intuition, this should work as follows:

```
//python_main.i
%module(package "MainNSPack") MainNSPack

%include python_a.i
%include pythom_b.i

//python_a.i
%module(package="MainNSPack.Apack") Apack
%{
    #include "A/Class.h"
%}

%include "A/Class.h"

//python_b.i
%module(package="MainNSPack.Bpack") Bpack
%{
    #include "B/Class.h"
%}

%include "B/Class.h"
```

The questions (problems) are the following:

1. I've tried to learn how `package` directive works when doing `%module(package="Apack") Class` but it seems to have no effect on generated files
2. When importing say `Class`, Python will look for the binary `_Class` - it's hard coded in initialization code within generated swig python files. Does it mean that I have to have separate binary for each of my classes.
3. If answer to 2) is yes, then how can this be handled with Visual Studio environment? I have a single project which contains all SWIG .i files. If I specify different module names then multiple .py files will be produced. But it produces a single DLL. And it seems that this will not work because multiple py files would try to refer to different binaries...